# Managed package components returning blank page

Tags: managed-package

I have installed a managed package in an org and assigned the user an appropriate permission set and when clicking the lightning component it returns a blank page

[image]

here MFSettings is a lightning component it is not working but it works fine in the org in which it was namespaced and packaged. What am I missing here can anyone point out

```
<script>        

$Lightning.use("MFPT:CMP_MFApp", function() {
    console.log('app invoked');
    $Lightning.createComponent("MFPT:CMP_MFObjects",{},"lightning",
    function(component) {       
        console.log('component invoked');
    });
});
```

this is what i gave in vf page and then in CMP_MFApp app am calling the two components

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">

   <aura:dependency resource="MFPT:CMP_MFSettings"/> 

   <aura:dependency resource="MFPT:CMP_MFObjects"/>    

</aura:application>
```

Comment: Ensure your org is lightning enabled and ensure your references in lightning out have appropriate namespaces and are not using c:

Comment: yeah I checked that too everything is fine but couldn't find out what's the issue is

Comment: Can you check if there are any console errors ? And if you have defined a div tag with Id=“lightning”

Comment: @dinesh Can the user in the subscriber org access the `CMP_MFApp` application outside the Visualforce page?

Comment: @Sumuga there are two console errors 1.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (logo180.png)

Comment: @Sumuga another one Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (lightning.out.delegate.js?v=1512966213440:177)

Comment: @DanielBallinger no they can't access VF page is the container of lightning component

Comment: the silly mistake cost me 3 days of my time :) seriously thank you guys for spending your time :) got the answer and the console error also got clear thank you guys :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the above details looks like CMP_MFApp is the component application, just try to include Acess="global" in your application

`<aura:application access='global' extends="ltng:outApp">`

Faced the same issue long back